# PHP password_hash and password_verify Not Working with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I am using `password_hash` to store passwords in a MySQL database field of type VARCHAR(255). When I try to login the user and verify credentials, the `password_verify` function always returns false.

Here is the code excerpt that stores the password in the MySQL database:

```
$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Generate API Key
$api_key = $this->generateApiKey();

// Insert Query
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user(email, password, name, api_key, status) values(?, ?, ?, ?, 1)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $email, $password_hash, $name, $api_key);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

And the piece of code that checks the password:

```
// Query user by email
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($password_hash);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    // Found user with that email address
    // Now verify the password

    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    if (password_verify($password, $password_hash)) {
        // User password is correct
        return TRUE;
```

Then I wrote this test code and grabbed the data straight from the MySQL field and it still fails. When I create the password_hash in the same file ($hash2 in the file below) - then the password verifies correctly.

```
$password = 'pass1234567890';
$hash = '$2y$10$JLP/pPei6RYRdUmoH8H5RO7iJyImOtrBLsrRRfq3XpeqNE3lQ/l7O';
$hash2 = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

echo $hash . " - " . strlen($hash);
echo "<br />";
echo $hash2 . " - " . strlen($hash2);
echo "<br />";

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo "Password Valid!";
} else {
    echo "Password invalid!";
}

echo "<br /><br />";

if (password_verify($password, $hash2)) {
    echo "Password 2 Valid!";
} else {
    echo "Password 2 invalid!";
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is the right hash?

Comment: I grabbed the field straight from the database, although I did notice that every time I refresh my test page the $hash2 variable changes, but I am not 100% sure how crypt works to fully understand why.

Comment: Check your MySQL Character encoding; check your database encoding, check your table encoding and check your column encoding and collation. MySQL [should be using UTF8mb4_ character sets and collations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Also; for note; cost = 10 is FAR TOO LOW. Your cost value should be as high as practically possible for your server; typically 14+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proves that something is wrong with your hash

```
<?php
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$password = 'pass1234567890';
$hash = '$2y$10$JLP/pPei6RYRdUmoH8H5RO7iJyImOtrBLsrRRfq3XpeqNE3lQ/l7O';

$hash2 = '$2y$10$gMJKYZUc1FKSZBnsONxLOebOHj.uuEWSiCP0jo4Zv0iAHBz6iz.NG';

if (password_verify('pass1234567890', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}

echo "<br>";

if (password_verify('pass1234567890', $hash2)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Screenshot[image]

Comment: Understood, but `password_verify` should be able to verify any of the hashes made from that password correct?

Comment: @mattdonders I thing something is wrong with that hash. I created a new hash and my works perfectly. Try to update the record with my hash (if my example wors for you) and let me know if you get something else.

Comment: But what could be wrong? Hashes are the same length, I'm doing an INSERT into a VARCHAR(255) using `bind_param()` as well. The $hash in that test file is literally straight from thr database.

Comment: So you're saying, delete the user manually, recreate them and try this again?

Comment: it can be that it was and extra character when you set the password? space or can be many other things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71455/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-mattdonders).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the probme was that I stored the database connection query in another file which included the same variable that I used for fetching current password, so what happened was that first I assigned a variable "password" to current password and then included my connection query file which had the same variable "password" therefore what happened was that, "password" variable of signup form was reassigned by "password" variable of connection query, and that's why it actually hashed another password. So by changing the variable name this problem was solved.

Here is my code for reference,

signup.php

```
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    
    include 'partials/php/_dbconnect.php';
    $passwordHash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

_dbconnect.php

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "demo";

$connectionquery = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

which I changed to;

```
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $passwd = $_POST["password"];
    
    include 'partials/php/_dbconnect.php';
    $passwordHash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
password_verify($password,trim($password_hash)))
```

While I am unsure if it happened when the hash was stored or during retrieval, the password_hash had a space at the end. Trimming the hash before feeding it to password_verify fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your password type, is it varchar or Text, change to text hashing produces long text. this works for me

Answer (score -1):

Just make a variable for `if(password_verify($pass_input, $pass_db))`
where `$pass_input` is the value given from the textified form and `$pass_db` is the value stored in mysql (hashed)

Like this:

```
$verif_pass = (password_verify($pass_input, $pass_db));
if($verif_pass){echo "TRUE"} else {echo "FALSE";}
```

and just modify TRUE/FALSE as you want.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should adding a new variable solve the problem?

Comment: Not sure... maybe password_verify return a boolen value TRUE if match and FALSE if failed. But the script working properly.

Comment: Im just tried without make a variable for it and working, the script like this .. if(password_verify($pass_input, $pass_db) === TRUE ){echo "TRUE";} else {echo "FALSE";}

Comment: What **exactly** does that change, compared to the given code? Does it only print something else? Or do you think the additional check `=== TRUE` makes a difference? Please edit your answer to contain all such information - keep in mind that others should be able to learn from it

Comment: **Please edit your answer to contain all information** - the given answer does not contain `password_hash` after all